# Flask api runs from python shell but not after hosting on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, api, flask, web-hosting

I am trying to expose the output of a program as an api. I am using flask to build my api. I want to host the same in a linux machine. When I run the script from my local, I am able to  find the output on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but when I try to run the same from the linux environment, it says 404 error or page not found error and there are no error codes like 404, 500 coming in my linux shell. How can I make it run on my linux environment as well? How can I test that it is working on linux?
Attaching code below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
#from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)    
class dtext(Resource):
    def get(self, result):
        return {'data': d.convert(result)}


categories= ["bus", "jack"]   
@app.route('/ec')
def returnResult():
  return categories[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: Can you try with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)` ?

Comment: you need to get the IP address of the linux machine, e.g.  `ip address` and use this IP in the browser instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Also, in your code you only declare the route `/ec` but in the text above you try to call `/`

Comment: @Martin If I remove /ec and give @app.route('/'), then when I enter the IP of my machine, it should display right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the 127.0.0.1:5000 connection on the Linux machine itself, or connecting from your other machine to the Linux machine?

You will need to ensure your application is listening on 0.0.0.0 or it will only accept connections from localhost (itself).

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

If you are not able to make any connections on port 5000 to your linux machine you'll need to take a look at your firewall rules.

Comment: I have made the changes to the code and also posted the same in the questions section. But still getting the same error "This site can't be reached"

Comment: Do you know the IP address/DNS name of the linux machine you are connecting to? It seems like this issue is with contacting the machine rather than with your code.

Comment: Yeah I know the IP adress, entering the same but still no response

Comment: And are you able to contact this Linux server over anything else? Can you ping the Linux server (lower level than ports so will check you have access at all)? It will depend how you've configured it, some examples are SSH, FTP, HTTP on other ports? Please check port 5000 is open on the Linux server.

Comment: I killed all running processes on port 5000 using kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:5000) and fuser -k 5000/tcp .. I am currently logged in to the vm. I am able to work in it, but when I ping it from the cmd,  it says not responding. Can this be the issue?

Comment: Yes this will be your issue, your host machine cannot contact the VM over the network, so this will be where to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Command line, run the app by typing `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`. (This bad idea for production code)
2. Then Open the Browser.
3. Type IP Address of the Linux Machine (`[IP ADDRESS]/ec`) and you should see result.
   Is your server a VM or on local network or on cloud?